# pyspark join 2 columns if condition is met, and insert string into the result

Tags: pyspark

I have a pyspark dataframe like this:

```
+-------+---------------+------------+
|s_field|s_check|            t_filter|
+-------+---------------+------------+
|  MANDT|   true|                 !=E|
|  WERKS|   true|0010_0020_0021_00...|
+-------+---------------+------------+
```

And as a first step, I split `t_filter` based on `_` with `f.split(f.col("t_filter"), "_")`

```
filters = filters.withColumn("t_filter_1", f.split(f.col("t_filter"), "_")).show(truncate=False)

+-------+---------------+------------+------------+------------+
|s_field|s_check|            t_filter|               t_filter_1|
+-------+---------------+------------+------------+------------+
|  MANDT|   true|              070_70|                   [!= E]|
|  WERKS|   true|0010_0020_0021_00...| [0010, 0020, 0021, 00...]
+-------+---------------+------------+------------+------------+
```

What I want to achieve is to create a new column, using `s_field` and `t_filter` as the input while doing a logic check for `!=`.

**ultimate aim**

```
+------------+------------+------------+
|                            t_filter_2|
+------------+------------+------------+
|                          MANDT != 'E'|
|        WERKS in ('0010', '0020', ...)|
+------------+------------+------------+
```

I have tried using `withColumn` but I keep getting error on `col must be Column`.

I am also not sure what the proper approach should be in order to achieve this.

Note: there is a large amount of rows, like 10k. I understand that using a `UDF` would be quite expensive, so i'm interested to know if there are other ways that can be done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this using `withColumn` with conditional evaluation by using the `when` and `otherwise` function. Following your example the following logic would apply, if `t_filter` contains `!=` concatenate `s_field` and `t_filter`, else first convert `t_filter_1` array to a string with `,` as separator then concat with `s_field` along with literals for `in` and `()`.

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as f
filters.withColumn(
            "t_filter_2",
            f.when(f.col("t_filter").contains("!="), f.concat("s_field", "t_filter")).otherwise(
                f.concat(f.col("s_field"), f.lit(" in ('"), f.concat_ws("','", "t_filter_1"), f.lit("')"))
            ),
        )
```

### Output

```
+-------+-------+--------------------+-------------------------+---------------------------------------+
|s_check|s_field|t_filter            |t_filter_1               |t_filter_2                             |
+-------+-------+--------------------+-------------------------+---------------------------------------+
|true   |MANDT  |!='E'               |[!='E']                  |MANDT!='E'                             |
|true   |WERKS  |0010_0020_0021_00...|[0010, 0020, 0021, 00...]|WERKS in ('0010','0020','0021','00...')|
+-------+-------+--------------------+-------------------------+---------------------------------------+
```

### Complete Working Example

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as f
filters_data = [
            {"s_field": "MANDT", "s_check": True, "t_filter": "!='E'"},
            {"s_field": "WERKS", "s_check": True, "t_filter": "0010_0020_0021_00..."},
        ]
filters = spark.createDataFrame(filters_data)
filters = filters.withColumn("t_filter_1", f.split(f.col("t_filter"), "_"))
filters.withColumn(
            "t_filter_2",
            f.when(f.col("t_filter").contains("!="), f.concat("s_field", "t_filter")).otherwise(
                f.concat(f.col("s_field"), f.lit(" in ('"), f.concat_ws("','", "t_filter_1"), f.lit("')"))
            ),
        ).show(200, False)
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for this. Let me check it out!